# Issues installing OSMnx in conda

Tags: python, conda, osmnx

I am having some troubles trying to install OSMnx in conda. Accorgding to OSMnx documentation on github https://github.com/gboeing/osmnx, I must run the following code in conda prompt in to install

```
conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
```

However, I get some warnings and errors I do not understand.

```
(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda config --prepend channels conda-forge
Warning: 'conda-forge' already in 'channels' list, moving to the top

(base) C:\WINDOWS\system32>conda create -n ox --strict-channel-priority osmnx
usage: conda [-h] [-V] command ...
conda: error: unrecognized arguments: --strict-channel-priority
```

I do not know what I am doing wrong. These are my conda specifications in case it matters

```
conda version : 4.5.4
conda-build version : 3.10.5
python version : 3.6.5.final.0
```

Thank you so much for your help.

Comment: your conda version is very old and probably doesn't support the option yet. Try upgrading conda to the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

You are using conda 4.5.4, which is a couple of years old. Update to the latest version and you'll be fine: `conda update conda`.